# Scala, Play - Problems with json type conversions when trying to implement a repository

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm a Scala newbie taking my first stabs at creating a webapp with Scala and Play 2.1.

I'm trying to create a UserRepository class that would be repository for User object to a MongoDB using reactive Mongo and reactive Mongo Play plugin.

Here's the thing that I don't understand. Consider this repository class:

```
@Singleton
class UserRepository @Inject() (db: DB) {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    val collection:JSONCollection = db.collection("users")

    def find(terms: (String, JsValueWrapper)*): Future[List[User]] = {
      find(Json.obj(terms:_*))
    }

    //Problematic method that sometimes works sometimes not
    def findOne(terms: (String, JsValueWrapper)*): Future[Option[User]] = {
       findOne(Json.obj(terms:_*))
    }

    def find(selector: JsObject): Future[List[User]] = {
       collection.find(selector).cursor[User].toList()
    }

    def findOne(selector: JsObject): Future[Option[User]] = {
       collection.find(selector).one[User]
    }

    def findByEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
       //problematic method works fine here
       findOne("email" -> email, "password" -> password)
    }

}
```

I wanted to create a find method that would use a vararg tuples to describe a Mongo selector object.
I use that in findByEmailAndPassword method in the repository class itself and it works fine.

**UPDATE:**

Calling findOne doesn't work in key -> value form if I supply only one tuple (regardless of where it's called from).
This works:

```
findOne(("email", "example@test.com"))
findOne("email" -> "example@test.com", "password" -> "foo")
val term: (String, JsValueWrapper) = "email" ->  "example@test.com"
findOne(term)
```

This doesn't work:

```
findOne("email" -> "example@test.com")
```

Why?

**UPDATE 2:**

I have since updated method to look like this (so I could provide Writes and Reads objects outside the repository class):

```
def findOne[V](terms: (String, V)*)(implicit reads: Reads[T], writes: Writes[V]): Future[Option[T]] = {
  val objMap = terms.map(entry => (entry._1, Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper(entry._2)))
  findOne(Json.obj(objMap:_*))
}
```

After this update, error no longer occurs. Although I still don't understand why it didn't work in the first place.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

However when I use the repository in a controller like this:

```
@Singleton
class TestController @Inject() (val userRepository: UserRepository) extends Controller {

  def testFind = Action { implicit request =>
    Async {
      //This call to findOne doesn't work
      val query = userRepository.findOne("email" -> "test@example.com")

      //This call works fine:
      //val query = userRepository.findOne(Json.obj("email" -> "test@example.com"))
      query.map(
        userOption => userOption.map(u => Ok("Found user: " + u.toString)).getOrElse(Ok("No user found.")))
      }
    }
}
```

When I call `userRepository.findOne("email" -> "test@example.com")` in the Controller class it doesn't work. But it does when I make a similar call to the same method in repository class - it works fine then (e.g. findByEmailAndPassword works ok). The error that I get when called from controller is:

```
Overloaded method value [findOne] cannot be applied to ((String, String))
```

I assumed it's implicit conversion issue but I do have all the same imports in the controller class as in the repository class yet String doesn't get converted to JsValueWrapper when method is used in Controller.

Any help would be appreciated, alternative solutions in declaring findOne(terms*) method are welcome as well, thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `object UserRepository` instead of the `@Singleton` annotation?

Comment: I use Guice as dependency injection to instantiate Controller classes and populate dependencies such as repositories (http://eng.42go.com/play-framework-dependency-injection-guice/). Reason being is that I dislike the hard coupling of static objects into other objects. It's easier/nicer to replace implementations later (e.g swap out mongo repositories for some other NoSql repositories) and easier mocking in tests. But it could also be that, since I come from Java world, I haven't figured out how to do dependency injection Scala way (e.g. cake pattern is a bit too hard for me at this moment).

Comment: @KresimirNesek Here's a [simplified Scala "DI" technique](https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/5203624) using default parameters. Regardless of what you think of that technique, you will save yourself a lot of grief if you give up on Java style coding and learn to code idiomatic Scala. Look at how Play is written and other Scala frameworks coded by people who really understand Scala (Spores, Akka, Scalatra). I believe if you think and code more functionally, DI is less useful (i think, because DI feels like it's a functional paradigm anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should additionally define another findOne(term: (String, JsValueWrapper)) method that internally delegates to findOne(terms: (String, JsValueWrapper)*) ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did manage to get method working like I'd expect (I added description in UPDATE 2). While your suggestion might work, real question is why is it not working the way I did it.